# My Protractor Script Error - Object Expected

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

Im learning the automation testing for angularjs application but im encounter object expected error on line 4 which point to first line of my script.

```
describe("Homepage", function() {
    it("Navigate to homepage", function(){
        browser.get("http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/login");
    });
});

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['protractor.js'] 
}
```

[image]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: How are you running the tests? Is there any error in the terminal/console?

Comment: Im running the test using protractor spec.js. No error on console.

Comment: Please show the content of file `C:\Users\admin\Documents\Protractor\protractor.js`

Comment: Please ensure that you installed protractor correctly

Comment: The protractor is shows on original thread. Please help.

Comment: the problem is in your config, not spec file. Show us its content

Comment: Show the config file in original thread.

Comment: @nicholas Can you confirm you are attempting to trigger via the cmd line? I could reproduce your error by clicking on the spec file directly which is not a valid way to trigger protractor scripts

Comment: Yes, I trigger the error from cmd.

Comment: @nicholas and can you confirm you have two separate javascript files? One containing the spec and one exporting the config. If so could you list the names of these two files?

Comment: @DublinDev The configuration file name config.js and the spec file name protractor.js. These two files are located at same directory.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should follow step by step :

> First, you should create a folder where you put protractor-conf.js and spec files in. 
>   You should create originally a file to save protractor config. In my project, the file's name is protractor-conf.js .

**Step 1** : Just install npm and protractor in project. Follow link [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) to install protractor in folder with terminal.

**Step 2** : Open protractor-conf.js and write following the link [config.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/example/conf.js)

**Step 3** : create spec files and run

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to run the test successfully.

**Step1**: create `config.js` file with below code

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
}
```

**Step2**: create the `spec.js` file with below code

```
describe("Homepage", function() {
    it("Navigate to homepage", function(){
        browser.get("http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/login");
    });
});
```

**Step3**: Now run `protractor config.js` from your project location after starting your webdriver in a separate terminal with the command `webdriver-manager start`

run `webdriver-manager update` if you get error in starting the webdriver.

Hope it helps you